# Transpose columns to rows in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Input :

```
MACK    113 445 25
JACK    345     
PIKER   30  23
```

I want the output to be :

```
MACK    113
MACK    445
MACK    25
JACK    345
PIKER   30
PIKER   23
```

[image: screenshot]

How can I do this?

Comment: If you select the cells you want to transpose, depending on the version you have, you can right click (on Windows) and select "transpose".

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Excel has a plugin called PowerQuery.

PowerQuery allows you to import data from your sheet, and run an 'unpivot' operation.

This is a very handy tool. It will take you a bit of time to set it up and get it working the first time, but once you do it will be useful for years and let you do this operation very quickly.

Here are some details on how to do it:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Unpivot-columns-Power-Query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098

Answer (score 0):

What you need is not to *transpose*, but to **un-pivot**.

The following is probably not the best way to get this done, but it works, and may be useful to save the day until someone comes with a better solution.

This assumes your pivot table is in `Sheet1` starting at `A1` (where `MACK` is); adjust to your case. In a Sheet2, enter the following:

```
A1: =Sheet1!A1
B1: =Sheet1!B1
C1: 1
D1: 2

A2: =IF(OR(B2="", A1=""), "", INDIRECT(ADDRESS(C2,1, 1, 1, "Sheet1")))
B2: =IF(OR(B1="", INDIRECT(ADDRESS(C2,D2, 1, 1, "Sheet1"))=""), "", INDIRECT(ADDRESS(C2,D2, 1, 1, "Sheet1")))
C2: =IF(D2=2,C1+1,C1)
D2: =IF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(C1,D1+1, 1, 1, "Sheet1"))<>"",D1+1,2)
```

Then copy the row 2 and paste it down for as many rows as necessary. Columns A and B will have the values you need, un-pivoted. Copy and paste elsewhere as values only.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, give your data some headings, for example:

```
Name Value1 Value2 Value3
```

1. Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
2. Select "Multiple Consolidated Ranges" > Next
3. Select "Create a single page field for me" > Next
4. Select your range (including headers) and click "Finish"

This will create a pivot table in a similar layout to your original data but includes totals.

5. Double Click on the bottom right grand total (which would have the value of 6 in your example)

This will create a new sheet that contains the data in the format you requested. You might want to delete a few columns and the blank entries to get to your requested output